# How to create non-overlapping, non-axis-aligned rectangles?

Tags: matlab, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a set of non-overlapping non-axis-aligned rectangles, and by non-axis-aligned I mean, the rectangle can be inclined with respect to x-axis and y-axis.

I know how to [detect whether two *aligned* rectangles overlap](http://articles.leetcode.com/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap/) but not how to do the same for *non-aligned* rectangles. Hoping someone can help me find an efficient algorithm for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

the first part can be done with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xy1= [1,0]
xy2= [0,1]
xy3= [1,2]
xy4= [2,1]


def pltRect(xy1,xy2,xy3,xy4):
    plt.plot([xy1[0],xy2[0]],[xy1[1],xy2[1]],'-b')
    plt.plot([xy2[0],xy3[0]],[xy2[1],xy3[1]],'-b')
    plt.plot([xy3[0],xy4[0]],[xy3[1],xy4[1]],'-b')
    plt.plot([xy4[0],xy1[0]],[xy4[1],xy1[1]],'-b')
```

The second part is a bit more complicated.
I'd start by rotating both rectangles until one (call it the master rectangle) is squared up with your x-y axes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Then you can check if any corner of the other rectangle is within the confines of the first by seeing if it's x coordinate is between the x-coordinates of the master rectangle, and repeating with the y- coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the above answer. I find another quite efficient algorithm on this website. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle. Please refer to the second highest answer. It is pretty brilliant.